# Request Always Permission in Cordova Geolocation

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, permissions, geolocation

It looks like PhoneGap has a config.xml setting to update a plist key in a project to set the Geolocation plugin's permissions from "while in use" to "always," and if I manually set my project's .plist file's key to `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` instead of the plugin's default `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` it sets the correct permission, but how do I tell the plugin to request the Always permission without having to dig into the platforms/ios/*.plist file? It looks like the plugin code has a check to see which permission to set, but I can't figure out how to request that it prompts the user for the correct permission with the JavaScript API.

See: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/src/ios/CDVLocation.m#L130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to platform/ios/ios.json
Find the following:

```
 "*-Info.plist": {
                    "parents": {
                        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": [
                            {
                                "xml": "<string />",
                                "count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

And replace "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" with "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"
So looks like following:

```
"*-Info.plist": {
            "parents": {
                "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": [
                    {
                        "xml": "<string />",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Run "cordova build ios"